# Debug Website on Apache Locally Without Running Apache as a Service

Tags: apache

I have a website I am developing.

I current access it at `file:///home/matt/website-dir/index.html`

I would like to be able to debug it at `http://127.0.0.1/`

I know that I can install Apache on my linux box and use the `file:///home/matt/website-dir` as the home directory.

Is it possible to not run apache as a service but as a standalone executable?

This would mean that when I clone the code for my website I do not have a dependency on apache being installed and running as a service?  I could just run it up as a debug executable:

Pseudo: `apache http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: Found how to run [Apache on a Windows Console](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html#wincons).  Anyone know how to do that in Linux?

Comment: It should be the same; just use the appropriate paths.